# WildFly Swarm Nullpointer @Inject bean

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly, weld, wildfly-swarm

I have a schedule service which gets its job via REST as JSON.

The `Resource` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import de.fszm.scheduler.controller.SchedulerController;
import de.fszm.scheduler.entities.MySchedule;

@Path("/schedule")
public class ScheduleRESTResource {

    @Inject
    SchedulerController scheduleController;

    @POST
    @Path("/job")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void schedule(MySchedule schedule) throws IOException {
        scheduleController.buildSchedule(schedule);
    }
}
```

The `ScheduleController`:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import de.fszm.scheduler.entities.MySchedule;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SchedulerController {



    public void buildSchedule(MySchedule schedule) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

}
```

The `SchedulerMain`:

```
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.wildfly.swarm.container.Container;
import org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive;

import de.fszm.scheduler.controller.SchedulerController;
import de.fszm.scheduler.entities.MySchedule;
import de.fszm.scheduler.rest.JaxRSActivator;
import de.fszm.scheduler.rest.ScheduleRESTResource;

public class SchedulerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Container container = new Container();
            container.start();

            JAXRSArchive appDeployment = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);

            appDeployment.addResource(ScheduleRESTResource.class);
            appDeployment.addResource(JaxRSActivator.class);
            appDeployment.addClass(MySchedule.class);
            appDeployment.addClass(SchedulerController.class);
            appDeployment.addAllDependencies();

            container.deploy(appDeployment);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the MySchedule ist just a POJO

My problem is that when I `POST` JSON to the I get a `NullPointerException` for the injected `SchedulerController`.

I also have a beans.xml in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and in my `pom.xml` I have the following dependency for CDI (weld)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using WildFly swarm 1.0.0 beta 6

What did I miss?

Comment: I found my Error. I just had to make the ScheduleRESTResource class a ManagedBean.

Comment: It was another Error. I had to use "jaxrs-weld" instead of "weld" dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the Swarm CDI fraction. 
Try adding this to your dependencies instead.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
</dependency>
```